# jQuery Timepicker external trigger

Tags: jquery, triggers, timepicker

I am having some trouble getting an external element to trigger my jQuery Timepicker from showing...

Timepicker:
http://timepicker.co/

Although I found this one as well? (if its better or recommended)
http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Mark-up:

```
<label for="startTime1">* Proposed Start Time:</label>  
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="timeinput form-control timepicker timepicker-with-dropdown text-center" id="startTime1" name="startTime1" placeholder="Start Time 1">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-fw" id="startTime1Trigger" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    </span>
</div>
```

- if I comment out this line.. and leave in ONLY the alert().. there is no error thrown?

Their example:

```
$('#spanExample').timepicker();
$('#openSpanExample').on('click', function(){
    $('#spanExample').timepicker('show');
});
```

My attempt:  (alert works.. timepicker doesnt change)

```
$('#startTime1Trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepicker('show');
    //$('#startTime1').timepicker('show'); //didnt work either
    //alert('triggered');
});
```

In developer tools..

I keep this error:  TypeError: n[t] is undefined

but I have no clue what it means.. or how to troubleshoot it.

Fiddle works.. but not my real-world example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k0r0rd4a/

Proposed Start Time 1 is the ONLY timepicker set-up to work currently..  (so only focus on that one field)

** It seems that something is going wrong once added to my over-all project/form..  as the jsfiddle seems to work properly..  but when added into my form.  (throws the odd error: TypeError: n[t] is undefined)

Comment: Based on your code I can see that it is working properly on the actual site...

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have multiple instances of `.timepicker`: you need to rely on the context of the element that receives the click event, i.e.:

```
$('#startTime1Trigger').on('click', function(){
    // Look for timepicker instance that is the parent's sibling
    $(this).parent().siblings('.timepicker').first().timepicker('show');
});
```

Also, do ensure that timepicker has been initialized for the element before attempting to access the method:

```
$('#startTime1Trigger').on('click', function(){
    // Look for timepicker instance that is the parent's sibling
    var $tp= $(this).parent().siblings('.timepicker').first();

    // Check if the method is defined before firing it
    if ($tp.timepicker())
        $tp.timepicker('show');
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#startTime1Trigger').on('click', function(){
    var $t = $(this),
        $tp = $(this).parent().siblings('.timepicker').first();
        
    if ($tp.timepicker())
      $('#startTime1').timepicker('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="startTime1">* Proposed Start Time:</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="timeinput form-control timepicker timepicker-with-dropdown text-center" id="startTime1" name="startTime1" placeholder="Start Time 1">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-fw" id="startTime1Trigger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Terry...  I do have multiple instances.  BUt I also tried using the ID instead of the class.. to target a specific timepicker.. and it still didnt trigger/open (show)..

Why would that be?  I'll try your suggestion and see how ti pans out.

Comment: @whispers That is very strange indeed: using the ID + `.timepicker('show')` should theoretically work, unless timepicker is not yet initialized on the element yet.

Comment: I have both the timepicker snippet and the new trigger snippet in the same place.. wrapped in this function.. that checks to make sure everything is loaded:

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});

Comment: Added link to jsfiddle as well as real project to see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: if I add your initialized check code..  and comment out the SHOW line and add in an alert.. it fires. (showing me 'is initialized')